# Available code to compute affine gap distance

Tags: edit-distance

Given the ubiquitous availability of code (in C, R, python, Java) which computes the Levenshtein edit distance, I am somewhat surprised at the lack of implementations of other edit distances such as the affine gap distance.
Are there easily usable libraries that compute this measure ?

Thanks!
ML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an open java similarity library here, may help: https://code.google.com/p/java-similarities/ and http://sourceforge.net/projects/simmetrics/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some affine gap implementations in other languages:

- [Python (Cython)](https://github.com/dedupeio/affinegap)
- [PHP](https://github.com/naoxink/PHP-affineGapDistance)